# JSON data into html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have this [json](/questions/tagged/json) response

```
 {
  "result_ok":      "true",
  "info_message":   "2015-04-24 - Recharge - 2.8 \n 2015-04-23 - Transfer -   15.0 \n 2015-04-21 - Recharge - 3.5 \n 2015-04-15 - Recharge - 27.7 \n 2015-04-14 - Recharge - 5.0 \n",
  "client_currency":"EUR",
  "balance_account":109.5
}
```

and I need to put the `"info_message"` data into HTML table like below. I don't know how to go through the data of a field?

```
 <p class="text-right big"><span class="accountCredit">+ 109.5 EUR</span></p>
 <table class="table cBlue5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2015-04-24</td>
            <td>Recharge</td>
            <td>2.8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2015-04-23</td>
            <td>Transfer</td>
            <td>15.0</td>
        </tr> 
...
```

Comment: Can you not format the `JSON` to be a proper and easier to parse tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the code you wish you had.

```html
<script>
  function create_html(json_obj) {
    return get_header(json_obj) +
             get_table(json_obj);

}

function get_header (json_obj) {
    return  '<p class="text-right big"><span class="accountCredit">+ '  +
          json_obj.balance_account.toString() + ' ' +
          json_obj.client_currency + ' ' +
          '</span></p>'
}


function get_table (json_obj) {
    return  ' <table class="table cBlue5"> <tbody> ' +
        get_rows(json_obj.info_message) +
        '</tbody></table>'
}

function get_rows (info_message) {
    return info_message.split(/\s*\n\s*/).map(get_single_row).join('\n');
}

function get_single_row (message) {
    var elements = message.split(/\s+\-\s+/)
    if(elements.length !== 3)
        return;
    return '<tr><td>' + elements[0] +'</td><td>' + 
                        elements[1] +'</td><td>' + 
                        elements[2] +'</td></tr>'
}
</script>

<body >
    <script>
  document.write(create_html( {"result_ok":"true", "info_message":"2015-04-24 - Recharge - 2.8 \n             2015-04-23 - Transfer - 15.0 \n              2015-04-21 - Recharge - 3.5 \n              2015-04-15 - Recharge - 27.7 \n              2015-04-14 - Recharge - 5.0 \n","client_currency":"EUR","balance_account":109.5}))
  </script>

  </body>
```

should do the job.

HTH Georg

Answer (score 0):

You have build you dynamically for the response. Please find the code below.

```
 var tableData = response.info_message;
 var rows = tableData.split('\n'), columns, tableBodyString = "<table><tbody>" ;

 for(int rowIndex = 0, count = rows.length; rowIndex < count; rowIndex++)
   {
      tableBodyString += "<tr>";
      columns = rows[i].split(' - ');
      for(int colIndex = 0, colCount = columns.length; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
        {
            tableBodyString += '<td>' + column[colIndex].trim() + '</td>'; 
        }
        tableBodyString += "</tr>";;
    }

    tableBodyString += "</tbody></table>";
    // Inserting the dynamically generated table into a wrapper div
    $("table_wrapper").html(tableBodyString);
```

Answer (score 0):

info_message is a string. You will need to break up the string into usable parts.

One option is to  *[Split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)* the rows using '\n' as a delimiter.

You will then need to split each rows columns using ' - ' as a delimeter (you can't use '-' or it will split the date parts).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please correct your json.

// if you are getting the json as a string then you should better parse it to object

// jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

```
var jsonData = {
      result_ok: "true",
      info_message: "2015-04-24 - Recharge - 2.8 \n2015-04-23 - Transfer - 15.0\n2015-04-21 - Recharge - 3.5 \n2015-04-15 - Recharge - 27.7\n2015-04-14 - Recharge - 5.0",
      client_currency: "EUR",
      balance_account: 109.5
    };

    var info_messages = jsonData.info_message.split('\n'); 
       // this will give you an array of the info messages
      // like ["2015-04-24 - Recharge - 2.8 ", "2015-04-23 - Transfer - 15.0", "2015-04-21 - Recharge - 3.5 ", "2015-04-15 - Recharge - 27.7", "2015-04-14 - Recharge - 5.0"]
```

Now, when you generate you table, you can interate the array of info_messages that you got above for each row. And in each row, you want to display each part of info message seprated by "-" as a column. So you'll further have to split each info_messages above at "-" like, inside the loop -

```
info_message.split(" - ") // see that you split by " - " and not "-"
// the above split will then give you an array of strings ["2015-0424","Recharge","2.8"] for the first info message
```

Comment: i am not the one who sends the JSON reponse , i only treat it

Comment: As long as the JSON gets parsed, it's ok.

Comment: Other's have shown how to dynamically generate the table but I'll leave that to you. Once you get the json parsed, it should not be a problem to get the data in table